# Opening a Gtk.Window that covers Launcher and Panel

Tags: unity, python, gtk

I am trying to create a GtkWindow that would be on top of all the windows. This includes Unity's Launcher and Panel. I am working on Kazam screen recorder and one of the options of the program is recording an arbitrary area of the screen.

For this, I open a GtkWindow and let user resize it and move it around the screen to the desired location. The problem is when user wants to resize the window over the Panel (or Launcher). It can't be done. It seems that window manager is preventing this.

I can move the window under panel and launcher if I ALT-drag it, but the problem because area selection window stays below Launcher and Panel.

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your window roll. You can use ccsm to force window rolls, but your going to have to play with them to get ones that will work.

You could also auto-hide the sidebar, but that does nothing for the top panel.

Other then that it's not really going to happen though. You wouldn't want to not be able to reach your panel/side bar ever.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use gtk_window_set_type_hint()? You should try 'GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN'. In combination with gtk_window_set_keep_above() it might solve your problem.

Most of my experiences are based on Gtk2, so I am not sure if this will work with Gtk3.